# Creating a Visual Basic chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a bar chart in VBA that will display a percent change for a specific month. The data would also need to be calculated within the macro. For example, the energy series show March-Feb/Feb rather than the just the month's data.

How would I go about doing this? I inserted an image of what I would like the display to be.

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

data:

[image]

what I would like the vba code to display:

[image]

```
Sub chart()
Dim i As Integer
Dim chart As ChartObject
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
(Left:=90, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
.chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2:D2", "B5:D5")
.chart.HasTitle = True
.chart.ChartTitle.Text = "1-month percent change for X month"
.chart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
.chart.HasLegend = False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the calculated percentages into an array and use the [series.collection(1).values property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.values).

```
Sub chart()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim chart As ChartObject
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = Range("C5:E5")

    ' calculate percent
    Dim cell As Range, pcent() As Single, prev As Single, curr As Single
    ReDim pcent(rng2.Count - 1)

    For Each cell In rng2
        curr = CSng(cell)
        prev = CSng(cell.Offset(-1, 0))
        pcent(i) = (curr - prev) / prev
        i = i + 1
    Next

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
(Left:=90, Width:=375, Top:=100, Height:=225).chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2:E2,B5:E5")
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "1-month percent change for " &   ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value
        .ChartType = xlBarClustered
        .HasLegend = False
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = pcent
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End With
End Sub
```